# how to open calling screen when App is killed , I am using agora.io

Tags: flutter, agora.io

I am using agora_rtc_engine for video calling.

I have tested the Firebase background message but the documentation mentions:

> Since the handler runs in its own isolate outside your applications
> context, it is not possible to update application state or execute any
> UI impacting logic. You can however perform logic such as HTTP
> requests, IO operations (updating local storage), communicate with
> other plugins etc.

Source https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage/

How I can display incoming call screen when Firebase notification arrived in the background when App is killed?

I also use [callkeep](https://pub.dev/packages/callkeep). It shows phone's default calling screen but when I click on answer call it starts the call. I am not able to navigate to specific screen.

Thanks.

Comment: i am also looking for solution... have you handle it please let me know... i am very thankful to you...

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that you can try - using the [CallKeepPerformAnswerCallAction](https://pub.dev/documentation/callkeep/latest/callkeep/CallKeepPerformAnswerCallAction-class.html) event you can bring your app to foreground using [bringtoforeground](https://pub.dev/packages/bringtoforeground)

Comment: i am also looking for solution... have you handle it please let me know... i am very thankful to you...